# How to prepare a rigged character model to be imported as a humanoid in unity?

Tags: unity, skeletal-animation, mecanim, rigging

I want to import a character as a humanoid to be able to use masks on animation system. I used proper human structure but unity gives some errors when I want to turn it from generic to humanoid and says some bones are not in the right place or have a wrong name.

The questions is how should a rigged model be prepared in modeling program to be imported in unity as humanoid?

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity has a doc file for this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AvatarCreationandSetup.html

By following the underlined red texts you probably find your answer but i think your problem is a bad avatar mapping: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Avatar.html